# Calculating a previous date interval with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

Here's an interesting problem I came across when building this application, and was wondering what the best way to do it would be.  I have a specific interval of dates, given to me in **month, year** format.

```
Jan 2014 - Feb 2014
```

Given this interval of dates, I need to calculate the previous time interval of this same length.  For example, for the above interval, the result would be:

```
Dec 2013 - Jan 2014
```

Now, I know one way to do this would be to:

- Calculate the times since Jan 1970 (or whatever date that is...) using `getTime()`
- Find the interval between these times in milliseconds
- Subtract from these times the above interval
- And then convert it all back into dates!

But I'm wondering if there is a better/faster way than w/ out all of these conversions.  Thanks.